# SwiftUI MultiviewResponder mystery crash

Tags: ios, swiftui

I came across this crash I can't explain, even after I boiling it down to the minimal components which would still cause the crash:
Repeatedly tapping the screen quickly (use two fingers) to hide/show an overlayed button with an explicit animation will crash the app under this VERY specific layout:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showControls: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.gray) // Removing this would fix it
            VStack {
                Text("someText")
                Text("anotherText") // Removing this would also fix it
            }
            if showControls {
                Text("Button")
                .zIndex(1) // Removing this would also fix it
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {  // Removing this would also fix it
                showControls.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code comments, any of these changes prevent the crash:

1. Remove the Rectangle from the bottom of the ZStack
2. Remove one of the two views from the VStack
3. Remove the zIndex (this will break the fade-out animation)
4. Remove the explicit animation call

Here is my console output:
[image: XCode debugging output]

I would like to know what's happening here, what's causing the crash ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing a similar problem which I can't explain at all.

Comment: @Chris no, I had to remove the animation. SwiftUI just isn't stable yet, I'm currently switching over to MVVM + UIKit without storyboards.
I've released my app to the App Store and there are some other mystery crashes related to navigation. Just my opinion, but if you are planning to release your app within the next year, I'd stay away from SwiftUI.

Comment: I have the same issue but it's hard to find the exact place where it happens because I know about it only from the apple reports. I'll try a fast-tapping technique to debug it, thanks. Anyways, the issue is still there.